# Is it possible to embed or link one inkscape SVG document inside another one?

Tags: svg, inkscape

I'd like to take one small SVG file (created with Inkscape), and embed or link it into another (bigger) one.  When displayed by a browser I hope to see the smaller one show up inside some placeholder of the bigger one.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

Prefer `<use>` to `<image>` as the later is rendered at a fixed resolution and doesn't scale as regular vector objects do in the current document. http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#ImageElement

But the element `<use>` cannot reference entire SVG files, its `xlink:href` attribute is a reference to an element/fragment within an SVG document (http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/struct.html#UseElement). The 'use' element can reference any local or non-local resource.

example:

```
MyLibrary.svg:
<svg (...)>
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" inkscape:label="upper-left-blue"
              style="fill:#729fcf;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none"
              id="upper-left-blue" height="200"/>

UseParts.svg:
        <use x="0" y="0" width="400" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
             xlink:href="MyLibrary.svg#upper-left-blue" xlink:type="simple"
             xlink:actuate="onLoad" height="400" id="use8793" xlink:show="embed"/>
```

Support of that feature may vary for different SVG editors/viewers, as far as I know it should work (at least) in Inkscape, Firefox and Batik.

Comment: I think it worth noting that Inkscape added support for this feature in the 0.91 release.  I added the Inkscape ppa to get this version on Mint 17 (14.04 Ubuntu).

Comment: @LeifCarlsen How exactly? I seem to not find how to do it in 0.91

Comment: I generate files with this feature outside Inkscape and view/render with Inkscape.

Comment: Hmmm... ok I tried and failed this before but maybe I need to try harder

Comment: Ha nevermind... usually its the user that makes the mistake... for reference I did just forget to add the xlink definition... I added the namespace to the top svg tag and suddenly it started working ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was forced to prefix the xlink:href with "./" to make it work in Inkscape.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`image`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#ImageElement) element and reference your SVG file. For fun, save the following as `recursion.svg`:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200" version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <circle cx="-50" cy="-50" r="30" style="fill:red" />
  <image x="10" y="20" width="80" height="80" xlink:href="recursion.svg" />
</svg>
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451135/embed-svg-in-svg/5451238#5451238

Comment: Somehow this results in "Linked image not found" message with Inkscape 0.48.4 on Windows at least.

Comment: maybe  prefix the xlink:href with "./" ?  works for me.